# which eclipse package is for web development?

Tags: eclipse

I'm looking at http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php and I have no idea which package to download. I'm coding in php, html, css, javascript. Which one is the right one for me? I don't see any of these languages in the descriptions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want standard Eclipsed (eg. not Aptana or something derived form eclipse) Then [PDT (PHP Development Tools)](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt) is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably download the Eclipse for JavaScript developers distribution, and then download the PHPEclipse plugin by following the following instructions: http://www.phpeclipse.com/wiki/General/PHPEclipseFAQ#InstallPHPEclipseinEclipsesince3.4M6